# Why does For Loop return the same function

Tags: r

Given the following function which returns a function

```
get_function <- \(model) {
  meanlog <- model[['Mean']]
  sdlog <- model[['SD']]
  \(x){ dlnorm(x, 
               meanlog = meanlog, 
               sdlog = sdlog)
  }
}
```

When I use the `get_function` as follow:

```
func <- distributions[['866064']] |> get_function()
```

func return the correct function. All work as expected, Great!

However, when I try to use the `get_function` in a for loop, like so:

```
output <- NULL
for(product in names(distributions)) {
  output[[product]] <- distributions[[product]] |> get_function()
}
```

All the functions loaded in the output list are the same, where they should be different because the model associated with each product in the distributions list is different.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the correct function loaded into the output list based on the different models in the distributions list?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please define the `distributions` variable here.

Answer (score 1):

We could initialize 'output' as a `list` instead of `NULL`

```
output <- vector('list', length(distributions))
names(output) <- names(distributions)
```

---

In the OP's loop, the assignment was done with a different object i.e. `ouput` instead of `output`

Comment: still does not really solve the problem. The output function loaded into each item in output list is the same and should be different

Comment: @FlippieCoetser now, it does with the update

Comment: was a type error in stack overflow. real code does use output

Comment: @FlippieCoetser can you `print(product)` it should be the same as you showed.  I am guessing that if it is a dataframe, its name got changed by appending `X` as prefix

Comment: print(product) give the correct list. When I print(distributions[[product]][['Mean']]) and print(distributions[[product]][['SD']]) I also get the correct values.

Comment: @FlippieCoetser can you try the code I showed

Comment: > output <- vector('list', ncol(distributions))
Error in vector("list", ncol(distributions)) : invalid 'length' argument. distributions is not a dataframe. It is a named list

Comment: @FlippieCoetser if you can update your post with a small example for testing, that would be useufl